# run a sub in all open MDIChild forms

Tags: .net, mdi, mdichild

I have a MDI windows application. 
The user has the ability to modify control properties (eg for colors). Every MDI child form contains a sub called ApplyMyUserProfile which sets the colors.

I would like am trying to find a way to immediately run ApplyMyUserProfile on 
every (open) MDI child window. I can identify the open child forms, but I 
don't know how to tell each of those forms to run ApplyMyUserProfile() for each form.

This is what I am trying to do ::

Private Sub ModifyUserProfileParametersInOpenForms()

Dim FormName As String = ""

' loop through all open 'MDI child forms

For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms

If frm.IsMdiChild Then

FormName = frm.Name

Debug.Print(FormName) ' this correctly shows me the open MDI child forms

' every MDI child form has a sub called ApplyMyUserProfile() 
 ' this sub will modify the control properties (color etc) that relate to each 
 ' form

frm.ApplyMyUserProfile()

' this creates an error "ApplyMyUserProfile is not a member of 
 ' Systems.Windows.Forms.form

frm.Refresh()

End If

Next frm

End Sub

' Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

```
 For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
```

' loop through all open MDI child forms

```
        If frm.IsMdiChild Then

         If frm.Name <> "frmMyUserProfile" Then

            CallByName(frm, "Form_ReloadUserProfileParameters", CallType.Method)

            End If

        End If

    Next frm
```

'note
'Form_ReloadUserProfileParameters() is a public sub that must be on each of the child forms. Whatever is in this sub will be executed on the sub!  (child)
'perfect!